# Is there somethign similar to the Windows Task Manager for the android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I was studying some tutorials on Android programming and I realized that pressing the `Home` button on the emulator takes me tot he phones `Desktop`, but my sample that was running at the time only goes to the background and does not get destroyed. However, if I press the return button, the app is destroyed as well. So I am assuming there might be other apps running int he background as well, those which I am not aware of. Is there something in the android emulator resembling the task manager from windows, which shows what apps are currently running on the phone? I don't have a smartphone with me, but I remember seeing something like that on my friend's smartphone a few days ago. It wasn't an external app but was something built into the phone, I could access it by going to Settings or something.

Is there a task manager built into the android emulator, or is there any other way I can see such things through the SDK debugger?

Comment: Setings -> Apps (or Applications) depending on which Android version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the settings, there is a list of currently running processes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First , Leaving the activity does not mean the process ends, It is just not invisible . When the Os needs more memory ,it will be recovered.

If you want to have a backup process, you can start a back service.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I end a process (only works on Android 4.0+).

Instead of pressing **home**, press **recent** and **swipe away** the process you want to end. Then press home (or back).

You can also use this to close those nasty apps that prevent you from closing them by not allowing back button to work on their main screens.

This is much quicker than having to go to settings, etc.